# How can I list the files in a zip archive without decompressing it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, zip

How can I get the equivalent of an `ls` of a .zip file (not gzip), without decompressing it, from the command shell? That is, how can I list the different files compressed within my .zip archive?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Perreal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15517826/119527) is right, but I recommend installing [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/) (look for it in your distribution's package manager). Then, for any kind of archive file, bzip2, gzip, tar... you have just one command to remember :

```
als archive_name
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works with LZMA, yes. Technically, atool is just a clever Perl script that wraps around the existing programs on your system. If you have unrar installed, it will work with rar files, if you have 7zip, atool will know 7z, and so on...

Answer (score 147):

[Use unzip with](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) `-l` option:

```
unzip -l file.zip
```

Comment: Link in original response gets a HTTP 403 for me, but the man page has the info about it. (Run `man unzip` or [visit this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip).)

Comment: `unzip -l file.zip` only lists files and folders in the first level, not files inside those folders.

Comment: that's not correct, at least with the version I'm working with. it does give a recursive listing.

Comment: @perreal what do you mean by recursive list? Do you mean if there are zips inside a zip?

Comment: I mean files in directories in the zip, @PeterMoore.

Comment: oh yeah I agree that definitly works for me.

Answer (score 22):

The `less` utility is capable of peeking into a `zip` archive.

Less comes bundled with Unix and there is no need to install als.
The output is scrollable (paged) and does not log things to the terminal (unlike unzip -l mentioned in the other answer).

As per https://superuser.com/a/216675/249975,

So simply use `less filename.zip`

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and work fine.  But does not work On MacOS 10.15.7

Comment: indeed, for Mac OS, need to use `unzip -l file.zip` as shown in other ansers in this page

Answer (score 15):

To view the contents of a zipped file without unzip by using this command

```
unzip -l file.zip
```

For tar files, we can use

```
zcat <archived-file>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
zipinfo -1 filename.zip
```

It returns only filenames, and no more, example (response):

```
listing.html
my_data.csv
super.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `lesspipe` in Debian/Ubuntu, it also can list many other archive types:

> ```
>      *.arj
>      *.tar.bz2
>      *.bz
>      *.bz2
>      *.deb, *.udeb
>      *.doc
>      *.gif, *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.pcd, *.png, *.tga, *.tiff, *.tif
>      *.iso, *.raw, *.bin
>      *.lha, *.lzh
>      *.pdf
>      *.rar, *.r[0-9][0-9]
>      *.rpm
>      *.tar.gz, *.tgz, *.tar.z, *.tar.dz
>      *.gz, *.z, *.dz
>      *.tar
>      *.jar, *.war, *.xpi, *.zip
>      *.zoo
> ```

Usage:

```
lesspipe file.zip
```

[reference](http://maemo.org/development/documentation/man_pages/lesspipe/)

Comment: Can you explain in a sentence what lesspipe is about? And provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "zmore archive_name".
It will list archive and it content.

Comment: zmore is a file perusal filter for crt viewing of compressed text. If you compress more than one file, it shows the first file only. (perreal's answer is effective that's why i purpose zmore to get more information about compressed file tools)

Answer (score 2):

I'll add in the following option, as I found it was by far the most convenient approach for my purposes (exploring contents of a 2GB tar, with tens of thousands of files and directories).

Using `archivemount` was the most useful method for me.

This is performed as follows:

```
mkdir mount-point
archivemount archive.tar.gz mountpoint
cd mount-point

umount mount-point
```

**Explanation**

You need to create an empty folder as your mount point. Easiest is to just create that folder within the folder where you have the archive file, as per above example. Although you can create it anywhere you like. Just change `mount-point` in the command accordingly.

Once you `cd` into the `mount-point` folder, you'll have a normal Linux folder and file tree to explore with any commands that you'd otherwise use to explore, find, cat, edit, ls, etc., folders and files in Linux. Very handy.

Use `umount` to unmount the archive once you are done

Note, you may need to first install `archivemount`. E.g, `sudo apt install archivemount`.

#### Why I found this so useful

I basically wanted an easy way to investigate the contents of a large tar file. Just having a massive text output (tens of thousands of lines) of the folder and file names wasn't particularly useful for me. Even after figuring out ways to pipe that content through other post-processors.

You can use this method with zip files, tar files, and those compressed with gzip, bzip, or compress.

Full details on `archivemount` are [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/archivemount.1.html).

A good write-up on it is [here](https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-mounts-an-archive-for-access-as-a-file-system).

This quote (from that article) summarises how flexible this tool is:

> [Because archivemount via FUSE] exposes its filesystems through the Linux kernel, you can use any application to load and save files directly into such mounted archives. This lets you use your favourite text editor, image viewer, or music player on files that are still inside an archive file. Going one step further, because archivemount also supports write access for some archive formats, you can edit a text file directly from inside an archive too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using zless if you would like to browse a single zipped file.  This may be less useful when the zip contains multiple files.

Per the description from the man page:

> Zless is a filter which allows examination of compressed or plain text files one screenful at a time on a soft-copy terminal.  It is the equivalent of setting the  environment  variable  LESSOPEN  to  '|gzip  -cdfq  --  %s',  and  the  environment  variable  LESSMETACHARS  to  '<new‐line>;*?"()<>[|&^`#$%=~',  and  then running less.  However, enough people seem to think that having the command zless available is important to be worth providing it.

Some other handy "z" utilities are zcat and zmore (mentioned in previous answers), zdiff and zgrep.

Regarding answering the original question, how to view the contents of a zip, I prefer zipinfo followed by unzip -l.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, using just the latest version of Zip (3.0) to list filenames only:

```
> zip -sf zip300xn.zip
Archive contains:
  Contents
  LICENSE
  README
  README.CR
  WHATSNEW
  WHERE
  zip30.ann
  zip.txt
  zipcloak.txt
  zipnote.txt
  zipsplit.txt
  zip.exe
  zipnote.exe
  zipsplit.exe
  zipcloak.exe
Total 15 entries (770278 bytes)
```

Answer (score -1):

To list/view the contents of a compressed file on a Linux host without uncompressing it (and where GZIP is installed), use the "zcat" command.

zcat compressedfilename |more

Comment: This is not an answer to my question; it's about zip, not gzip; and not about cat'ing the contents but listing which files are in the zip archive.