# Untar in R: How to open archive, search for file, extract match

Tags: r, extract, wildcard, archive

I need to untar specific files from a high number of archives. The names of the desired files have a dynamic part in them, so my approach is a wildcard search.
The following approach does not work:

```
untar(archive, files = glob2rx("*name"))
```

At this point, I need to extract the whole archive and search the files or use untar with list = TRUE to get the filename.
Both takes too much time. How can I open the archive in the memory, look for the file and extract that file only? Surely there is there another efficient way to solve this?

EDIT: It's tar.gz files I'm working with.

Comment: Possibly relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517731/how-can-i-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-file-without-decompressing-it