# Discover zip/gzip contents before uncompressing it

Tags: unix

Is there a way to get the file and or directory names from a zip file before uncompressing it?

For example:

```
my.zip
==>
   - hello/
      - second.txt
   - new.xml
```

I'm looking to be able to do this for both the .zip and .gzip compression.

Comment: This sounds like more of a [Super User](https://superuser.com/)/[Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question...

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/462788 https://askubuntu.com/q/392885 https://stackoverflow.com/q/15517731/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `unzip` utility:

```
unzip -l my.zip
```

Comment: Oh, no, for gzipped files, you can use the `gunzip` utility: `gunzip -l my.gz`.